# JavaScript radio onclick processed before UI reflects selection

Tags: javascript, onclick, radio-button

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
var radios = form.elements["option_filter"];
for (var i = 0, max = radios.length; i < max; i++) {
    if (typeof (radios[i].value) !== 'undefined') {
        radios[i].onclick = function () {
            var l = this.nextElementSibling.innerText;
            <code to create a path containing selection>
            window.location.replace(dest);
        }
    }
}
```

which works fine, except that when a radio is clicked, the selection is considered checked in code, but that is not reflected in the UI ... the radio button remains blank as the redirect is processed.

I tried having it sleep a bit between the onclick firing and the redirect, to no avail.

How do I get the UI to reflect the selection change so that the user sees it selected while waiting for the new page to load?

Answer (score 1):

To get the UI to reflect... you'll need to set the value of the target radio button to a value...

```
radio[i].value = "whatever"
```

Also remember that the value set must match the `name` of one of the radio buttons in your options...

Comment: Confused by your intention. Given that radio[i] is present to be clicked, it already has a value (which it does...it's not undefined), thus it would be a case of radio[i].value = radio[i].value. I thought perhaps you meant I needed to do radio.value=radio[i].value, but that doesn't affect it either.

Comment: Could it be that the click event fires before the radio change event? Do I need to process on the radio change event instead?

Comment: I believe `onchange` or `oninput` (depending on the end goal) would be more appropriate...